# Best way to customize how core data populate NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsarraycontroller

So far all the examples I can find are direct binding between Core Data and NSArrayController. That means each NSArrayController maps exactly one entity.

Is there a way to customize what's get populated into the NSArrayController?

For example, I have two entities:

```
FileMetaData
    ID
    FileName
    FileSize
    Owner(relationship m..1 to SystemUser)

SystemUser
    ID
    FirstName
    LastName
    Files(relationship 1..m to FileMetaData)
```

I have one NSArrayController to populate a tableview that has two column, one is "FileName", and the other one is "UserName". UserName comes from FirstName + Lastname in SystemUser entity. The NSArrayController is set to bind with FileMetaData.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to easily get a `UserName` property (`FirstName` + `LastName`) is to define a category on the `SystemUser` class with a `UserName` method that returns the `FirstName` and `LastName` properties duly concatenated.

Then in your various bindings you can bind to the `UserName` property. Typed directly into the browser, so not tested, a `UISupport` (or any other name) category `SystemUser` could look like this:

```
// In SystemUser+UISupport.m

- (NSString *)userName
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", self.FirstName, self.LastName];
}
```

In order for the bindings to work if the `FirstName` or `LastName` properties change, you might want to implement this method, too:

```
+(NSSet*)keyPathsForValuesAffectingUserName
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects: @"self.FirstName", @"self.LastName", nil];
}
```

Finally, for completeness, you can declare your new-fangled read-only property in the header file:

```
// In SystemUser+UISupport.h

@property (readonly) NSString *userName;
```

Comment: Thanks! I did this with adding another field in the SystemUser class and update the fullName field by NSManagedObject's willSave() method. But I think your way is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think Monolo's solution is better than mine, but just for an alternative, I will post my solution as well.

My approach is to add a new "displayName" field in SystemUser.m. And implement NSManagedObject's willSave() method.

```
-(void)willSave
{
    if (self.displayName == nil)
    {
        self.displayName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.lastName];
    }
}
```

This way the displayName field gets updated before CoreData attempts to save the entity.